# Generic method info from List(T) by type and dynamic parsing

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is it possible to get methodInfo based on wanted type like this:

```
var wantedType = typeof(propertyReference);
var methodInfo = typeof(List<wantedType>).GetMethod("Contains", 
                    new[] { typeof(wantedType) });
```

...and also this:

```
var list ="(some, list, here)".Split(new[] { ',' }, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(wantedType.Parse).ToList()
```

If yes, what would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "wanted"? Return type or parameter?

Comment: I don't know if this propertyReference will be int, string, or datetime, it's determined at runtime. And I want to avoid writing switch - case for each of possible types that I can get with `switch (Type.GetTypeCode(propertyReference.Type))`

Comment: Just get the method with the specified name and then check the ReturnType property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `wantedType` is a runtime-type you need to get the generic definition of the type before. Use [`MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this:

```
var t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(wantedType);
```

Now you can call any of its method via reflection as if it where a normal type:

```
t.GetMethod("Contains").Invoke(myList, new[] { instanceOfWantedType });
```

where `MyValue` is an instance of the type `wantedType`.

Your second example works similar, just call the `Parse`-method via reflection:

```
var m = wantedType.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
var list = stringArray.Select(x => m.Invoke(null, new[] { x })).ToList()
```

But be aware that the list is quite unspecific, as all is elements are of type `object`.

Comment: This throws exception if the type is string, so I have to handle that separately? And for int for example it says: `Ambiguous match found.`

Comment: There´s no method `Parse` on type string. So it should a NullReferenceException. I didn´t handle that case, I assumed your wantedType will allways have the `Parse`-method.

Comment: And how about for the int and that ambiguous match?

Comment: @ShP Updated. You need the overload of `Invoke` that sets the types for the arguments.

Comment: I'm still getting error, but different now: Method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' declared on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' I don't know if this helps, but I'm trying to pass it to `Expression.Call` method.

Comment: @ShP Seems like another problem not really related to the question so far. Maybe you should update the question with your actual code or create a new one. For the sake of the current question this answer should work.

Comment: The problem is the list which is generated like this is list of objects, not really list of wanted types, not list of integers or other types.

Comment: @ShP And how should we know that from your question? What is the lists runtime-type? I doubt it is `object`. Anyway even then you should first write your code *without* reflection as if the types were known at compile-time. Then, when you knwo what your lists actually *Contains* you may put this information into the reflection-code.

Comment: the part of your code that you provided for list generation will generate list of objects, regardless what's the `wantedType`. So, if `wantedType` is for example int, appropriate list should be list of int. The only way that I manage to generate it properly is like this: https://gist.github.com/vsavic/8665edc432a288092fc7834b334a2cbd Maybe this will help to understand what I wanted to achieve. This works now, but maybe it's not the best solution.

Comment: @ShP There´s no way to infer the type at *compile*-time when you know it only at *runtime* That´s why your list will allways be `List<object>`. You have to cast the elements to int, no way around this.

Comment: Check the gist link that I posted, this works as I wanted, but as I said, I was just wondering if that's the best way... :) So in this sample, `list` is list of objects, and `properList` is list of int's if wanted type is int.

Comment: @shp Isn´t that what I suggested in my answer? And yes that´s the only way to do this.

Comment: It is, so maybe just update your answer with code from my sample, so if someone else have the same problem can just use it like that. And thank you for your help.